# how can i make eclipse stop formatting my code

Tags: eclipse

I am programming using eclipse galileo, but once i save my code it formats my code automaticaly in a way i do not like, for example:

this is how i want my code look like:

```
String sql = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM  PMT_EXPEDIENT PMT"
        + "  INNER JOIN SIGAC_ASSISTENCIA SA ON ( PMT.EXP_IDENTIFICADOR_EXPEDIENT = AST_ID_EXPEDIENT_PMT AND "
        + "  PMT.EXP_ID_RECURS <> SA.AST_ID_RECURS) ";
```

but once i save my code is formmatted this way by eclipse automaticaly:

```
String sql = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM  PMT_EXPEDIENT PMT"
+ "  INNER JOIN SIGAC_ASSISTENCIA SA ON ( 
PMT.EXP_IDENTIFICADOR_EXPEDIENT = AST_ID_EXPEDIENT_PMT AND "
+ "  PMT.EXP_ID_RECURS <> SA.AST_ID_RECURS) ";
```

is there anyway to avoid this and take total control of code formatting in eclipse ?

Comment: What programming language?

Comment: Galileo? The current version is Mars. You're 6 years behind. Anyway: Preferences - type "Save actions", uncheck the automatic formatting on save.

Comment: i know,  but i am forced to use it. this did not work for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Windows -> Preferences
2. Type 'save actions' -> Choose 'Save actions' under "Java -> Editor" section
3. Uncheck "Perform the Selected actions on save" or uncheck "Format Source Code" alone, if you wish

Hope that would remove the auto-formatting.

***Edited:***

If the above doesn't solve the issue,

- right-click on your project -> properties -> java editor -> Save actions.
- Uncheck "Format Source Code" if checked.

The project setting takes preference over the global setting.

Comment: In that case, right-click on your project -> properties -> java editor -> Save actions. Uncheck "Format Source Code" if checked. This project setting takes preference over the global setting.